# How to pass variable's value from subreport to main report and show/hide detail band on the basis of that value in iReportDesigner Jasper Reports?

Tags: jasper-reports, return-value, ireport, subreport

I am storing Value of one field in a variable in subreport. This variable I am returning to Main report. On the basis of this value I want to show/hide detail band 2. But I am not able to implement this as the value returned by the subreport is always Null which is a shock to me as when I am displaying the same value in subreport itself it is giving me 2 (integer).  Please help me out with this.

Answer (score 0):

For the First part of your question

> ***The value returned by the subreport is always Null***

In your Main report please cross check the following things.

- You return variables from your sub report as in specified in [here](http://www.scribd.com/doc/91916205/100/Returning-Values-from-a-Subreport).
- If the subreport and the text field in which you're using the returned value are placed on the same band, you need to set `evaluationTime="Band"` for the text field.

For the later part of your question,

> ***I want to show/hide detail band 2***

- Using the report inspector, select detail band 2.
- Access the properties of the band, using the properties tab.
- You can find the property `PrintWhenExpression`.
- Edit its value to hide/display detail band 2.

The second part of the answer works on the following logic

**`PrintWhenExpression` will be evaluated at the start of the band rendering process, before starting to render the elements**.

So, if the sub-report too is in the same band, detail band 2 in your case, this method would not hold good.

Comment: On the basis of the value returned by the subreport, present in detail band 2, I want to show/hide detail band 2. I need a solution for this? I am using  new Boolean($V{myVar}.intValue()!=0) in PrintWhenExpression of detail band 2. But am not getting correct result since myVar is getting Null.

Comment: you can place your sub report in some other band before your detail band 2 is rendered. Then check whether you can toggle the visibility of your band.

Comment: @Gopinagh.R: Avoid referencing content on external sites because when the link ultimately expires--and it will--the value of the answer is diminished. The link to the guide is no longer available.